# PIGLatin Flattening multiple columns

Tags: apache-pig

Sorry folks I just started using PIG a few days ago. I have no Idea how to fix this problem. Any help would be really appreciated.

is there a way to make this code independent from the number of columns? As I am trying to put it all in one column but each cell as a single cell.

```
    C= FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN ($1);
    D= FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN ($2);
    E= FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN ($3);
    F= FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN ($4);
    G= FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN ($5);

X= UNION C,D,E,F,G;

DESCRIBE X;
DUMP X;
```

Cheers Joe

Comment: What you mean? you want to union all the columns.

Comment: Is each column a bag?

Comment: I have strings in every column. I just want them all to be in one. So the number of rows should increase in that case by 5. The aim is to make the query independent from the number of rows. And the other question is, if its possible, to make a nice onliner out of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no solution for this instead of using Foreach in Pig as the above you mentioned.
In `UDF also you need to store each column value in separate variables`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
FOREACH A
GENERATE FLATTEN(TOBAG($1, $2, $3, $4, $5));


FOREACH A
GENERATE FLATTEN(TOBAG(*));
```